# Column alignment (within rows) issue with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.6 to create a responsive page - and I am having problems getting the columns withing rows to align as I want.

I want my page to look something like this:

```
                                 Topics  |  Gallery One  Gallery Two  Gallery Three

Most Popular Photos                                        * Most Popular  o Latest
```

However, I have the following issues:

1. The form is displayed on the same row (visually), as the row containing the "Topics ..." line
2. The form is not floated right within it's own row

Here is my code:

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row float-right">
    <ul class="theme">Topics
      <li>Gallery One</li>
      <li>Gallery Two</li>
      <li>Gallery Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <h2 class="font-weight-light text-center text-lg-left mt-4 mb-0">Most Popular Photos</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Most Popular</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Latest</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit" name="submit"/>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <hr class="mt-2 mb-5">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* theme */
  ul.theme {
    padding: 5px 0px;
  }
  
  ul.theme li > a {
    color: #CACACA;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  ul.theme li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 4px;
  }
  
  ul.theme li a:hover {
    color: #275d9c;
  }
  
  ul.theme li:first-child { 
      border-left: 1px solid #CACACA;
      padding: 0px 4px;
  }
  
  ul.theme li.highlight {
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
  }
```

How do I fix these issues?

Comment: make this code available on sandbox....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

First of all, when you want to position content with Bootstrap, I suggest you to use `justify-content-` for horizontal positioning and `align-items-` for vertical positioning instead of using floating.

You have two rows inside the same `container` (the same as in your original code):

- `Topics|Gallery One  Gallery Two  Gallery Three` and
- `Most Popular photos                 • Most Popular • Latest   Submit`

All content in the first row should be positioned on the right side so simply add class `d-flex justify-content-end` to the first `row` which moves everything to the right side.

For the second row it's a little bit tricky because you want "*Most Popular photos*" in the same row as "*• Most Popular • Latest  Submit*" **but** "*Most Popular photos*" should be positioned on the left side and "*• Most Popular • Latest  Submit*" should be positioned on the right side. Adding `d-flex justify-content-end` or `d-flex justify-content-start` to the second `row` won't work because it would move both either to the left side or both to the right side. So, how can you kind of "separate" these two so that you can position "*Most Popular photos*" to the left side and "*• Most Popular • Latest  Submit*" to the right side **yet** still having both of them in the same `row`? **Solution: use Bootstrap's grid system.** You need to have two columns (i.e. use `col-6` twice) which makes up to 12 (6 + 6 = 12). You can have maximum of 12 columns per `row`, so if you use `col-6` twice, that means you separated your content into two same width columns. If you would use `col-2` and `col-10` that would result in narrow left part and wide right part.

Now that your content in the second `row` is "separated" into two same width columns, you can simply add `d-flex justify-content-start` to the first `col-6` (which moves "*Most Popular photos*" to the left side inside the second `row`) and `d-flex justify-content-end` to the second `col-6` (which moves "*• Most Popular • Latest  Submit*" to the right side inside the second `row`).

Regarding this white space in-between these two rows, you can solve this by applying a negative margin to the second `row` like this:

```
.move_up {
  margin-top: -3.5%;
}
```

```css
/* theme */

ul.theme {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin-right: 22px;
}

ul.theme li>a {
  color: #CACACA;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.theme li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 4px;
}

ul.theme li a:hover {
  color: #275d9c;
}

ul.theme li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #CACACA;
  padding: 0px 4px;
}

ul.theme li.highlight {
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}

.move_up {
  margin-top: -3.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class='container'>

    <div class='row d-flex justify-content-end'>
      <ul class='theme'>Topics
        <li>Gallery One</li>
        <li>Gallery Two</li>
        <li>Gallery Three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='row d-flex align-items-end move_up'>
      <div class='col-6 d-flex justify-content-start'>
        <h2 class='font-weight-light text-center text-lg-left mt-4 mb-0'>Most Popular Photos</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='col-6 d-flex justify-content-end'>
        <div class='form-check form-check-inline'>
          <input class='form-check-input' type='radio' name='inlineRadioOptions' id='inlineRadio1' value='option1'>
          <label class='form-check-label' for='inlineRadio1'>Most Popular</label>
        </div>
        <div class='form-check form-check-inline'>
          <input class='form-check-input' type='radio' name='inlineRadioOptions' id='inlineRadio2' value='option2'>
          <label class='form-check-label' for='inlineRadio2'>Latest</label>
        </div>
        <div class='form-check form-check-inline'>
          <button type='submit' class='btn btn-sm btn-success' id='submit' name='submit' />Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class='mt-2 mb-5'>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be doing what I wanted (in terms of positioning withing rows) - however, it seems to be imposing a minimum height on the elements - therefore the two rows have ended up taking quite a noticeably large percentage of the screen vertical size. Also, could you please add some explanation to what I was doing wrong - and how your suggestion/code fixes/addresses what I was doing incorrectly? Thanks

Comment: You want less white space between these two rows?

Comment: Yes, not only that, but the rows them selves seem to be "too tall". The height is automatically being calculated, so there is a lot of vertical whitespace. I used Chrome Inspector to check where this is coming from - expecting to see some prior selector applying margins or paddings - but I couldn't find anything, so I don't know why the rows are so tall.

Comment: I'm at work. I haven't had the chance to test it yet (will do when I get home later today), but I have upvoted your answer for the detail it gives, which will be helpful to not only me, but also, anyone who has a similar issue in the future.